# How to open Clawpack directories?

Tags: terminal, cd

We have to do simulate a tsunami for a school project using Geoclaw with Python, and I came across this tsunami example project on the Geoclaw official website: `$CLAW/geoclaw/examples/tsunami/chile2010` .

[image: Screenshot from official website]

I thought it was a thing preinstalled with Geoclaw so I typed `cd $CLAW/geoclaw/examples/tsunami/chile2010` in the Terminal, in order to open this directory.

But when I do it shows `cd: no such file or directory: /geoclaw/examples/tsunami/chile2010`.

So where in the world should I type this directory after installing Geoclaw?

Comment: What does this have to do with Python? `cd` is a shell command and you seem to not be able to find a directory

Comment: I'm trying to make the tsunami thing with python

Comment: Very poor explanation. I recommend you elaborate further with code snippets and so on.

Comment: I can see that. But your problem is that you can't find a file/directory in your system... This has nothing to do with Python and not much we can help with...

Comment: my question is where do I download the geoclaw file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind I found that I can install this thing from git clone as shown in here on the official website: http://www.clawpack.org/apps.html#apps